# How to convert this unix time string to java date

Tags: java, datetime

I got this time string "2015-07-16T03:58:24.932031Z", I need to convert to a java timestamp, I use the following code, seems the converted date is wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");
    Date date = format.parse("2015-07-16T03:58:24.932031Z");
    System.out.println("date: " + date);
    System.out.println("timestamp: " + date.getTime());
}
```

output:

```
date: Thu Jul 16 04:13:56 CST 2015
timestamp: 1436991236031
```

Is my date format wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. Be assured that any basic question on date-time handling in Java has already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to quote the Z, it's a timezone indicator. Instead, use the [`X` format specifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), for an ISO-8601 timezone.

Separately, you may want to pre-process the string a bit, because the part at the end, `.932031`, isn't milliseconds (remember, there are only 1000ms in a second). Looking at that value, it's probably microseconds (millionths of a second). `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't have a format specifier for microseconds. You could simply use a regular expression or other string manipulation to remove the last three digits of it to turn it into milliseconds instead.

This (which assumes you've done that trimming) works: [**Live Copy**](http://ideone.com/Md8sQ8)

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
// Note --------------------------------------------------------^^^^
Date date = format.parse("2015-07-16T03:58:24.932Z");
// Note trimming --------------------------------^
System.out.println("date: " + date);
System.out.println("timestamp: " + date.getTime());
```

Comment: result: date: Thu Jul 16 11:58:24 CST 2015
timestamp: 1437019104932
seems still not correct

Comment: @jamee: It's correct, it's just that you're in the CST timezone, so you're seeing the date interpreted in that timezone by the default `Date#toString`. That's an *output* issue, not an issue with the `Date` value. Normally you wouldn't use `Date#toString` (because **all** of `Date`'s timezone stuff has been deprecated for over a decade), you'd use `DateFormat` and/or `Calendar` and/or JodaTime and/or the various new date/time features in Java 8's [`java.time` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).